# Load JS (CSS) file from another JS (CSS) file on Objective C

Tags: objective-c, css, javascript

I'm trying to load an entire source library of JS/CSS from Objective C (Xcode) from a UIWebView with an HTML loaded. The problem is that in the library documentation, they say you just need to load one JS file, but inside it's requiring others JS. The question is how i have to arrange the files... Just one folder with all the sources? Nested folders containing the JS/CSS just as they come on the library? or Do I need to fix the path of the requires in order to load them (say absolute or relative)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest minifying all of your JS (CSS) into 1 file.  You can download tools to do this, but one easy free one online is: http://jscompress.com/

Using some command or a downloaded app would probably make the code-minify-debug process much quicker, but you can test out the idea using that online tool.